# C# WinForms - Event to detect mouse pointer moved to lower left corner of form or window

Tags: c#, winforms

A textbox control's visible property is set to false by default. When the user moves the mouse pointer to lower left corner of the window/form, the textbox should show up. When the mouse is moved away from the lower left corner, it should become invisible again.

What I've tried:

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Bounds.Contains(10, 100) && !coolTextBox.Visible)
        {
            coolTextBox.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            coolTextBox.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I think my if statement condition for checking if the mouse pointer is in lower left corner is not correct. Also, it's kind of tricky because the form/window is resizable by user so I have to account for that as well. The textbox itself is also placed in the lower left corner.

Answer (score 1):

Side note; this may well be a fairly terrible UI idea for various reasons relating to human psychology of user experience (read up on mystery meat navigation - a UI that hides the way it should be interacted with is by default poorly designed) and also making things hard work for touch users

Your form's 0,0 is in the top left corner so you're going to need to use the ClientSize property that return the size of the form area inside the border bars, where controls may live. We do this so that we can assess, given that the height of the form may change, whether the mouse pointer is near the bottom of the window

Your mouse move event will have an X and Y coordinate - to use these to determine if the mouse is in a 10x10 area in the bottom left:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  coolTextBox.Visible = (e.X < 10 && e.Y > this.ClientSize.Height -10);
}
```

I'm advising use of the client size because I don't think Mousemove events fire for the titlebar. If I'm wrong and they do, and the e.Y contains eg 20 when the pointer is touching the very top line of the client area (under the title bar) use `this.Height` instead (I'm on a cellphone and can't test this)

Comment: this is just for a personal project on my desktop pc. that code didn't work for me. could you write the whole code so I know I've done it correctly?

Comment: The line of code is the only line in the mousemove event handler - edited. If it still gives trouble put a breakpoint on the code line , run the app and then very carefully introduce the pointer into the bottom left of the form from outside the window (don't touch the window with the mouse otherwise the debugger will break, you'll go inspect the values, they will be wrong, you'll resume, it'll break again.. and get into a loop that is hard to break out of)

Comment: Still not working. The window is borderless using FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

Comment: @EsAMe The code posted is working, but the values are set too low, try to set them at coolTextBox.Visible = (e.X < 100 && e.Y > this.ClientSize.Height -100);

Comment: Yes, i wasn't sure what would reasonably be "the lower left corner" - feel free to experiment with the pixels given by altering the 10 to a different value, that matches your appetite for how large of a hit-box the "lower left corner" is considered to be

Comment: Still nothing. Tried different values. My PC is set to 150% scaling on Windows 10.

Comment: What does the debugger say `e.X`, `e.Y` and `this.ClientSize.Height` are, when you break it on that line of code by mousing into the very bottom left from outside the form?

Comment: I'm not good with debuggers. Do you mean the Output window? It doesn't say anything.

Comment: I recommend you get good; it will be a massive improvement to your productivity: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GPnTiFxkn9Y - there won't be anything in the output window because your code doesn't contain any print statements, but that's not how debuggers work. Debuggers allow you to step through your code one line at a time and look at the values of all the variables, and watch how the code flows. Take a look at the video

Answer (score 0):

You could use the size of the TextBox itself to determine the bottom left. This worked at different scaling options for me.  Also, make sure you've got the MouseMove event wired up.  Here I'm doing it in the constructor, but you could also do it via the designer:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    coolTextBox.Visible = coolTextBox.ClientRectangle.Contains(coolTextBox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));       
}
```

Comment: Then you've not described your setup well enough, or you failed to implement the suggestions correctly.   You said the form is borderless,  but the user can resize the form... so you must have code that allows this. It's possible these things are conflicting with each other. Show us more code...

Comment: you are right. I created a new project and it's working but on my original project it's not. probably because I have some quirks there which is conflicting with each other.